# JobService causes the app to crash

Tags: android, service, android-service, job-scheduling

I cretaed an example to know how JobService works. in the below code, i have the MainActivity with the method onclik() that starts the JobService. At run time, when onClikc methos is called
the App crashes without any logCat output but i receive a dialog saying: unfortunately, JobServiceTest_00 has stopped

please have alook at the MainActivity and the TestJobService , and let me kknow what causes this crash

note: the TestJobService is registered in the manifest file

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        ComponentName mServiceComponent = new ComponentName(this, TestJobService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(kJobId++, mServiceComponent);
        builder.setMinimumLatency(5 * 1000); // wait at least
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(10 * 1000); // maximum delay
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED); // require unmetered network
        builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true); // device should be idle
        builder.setRequiresCharging(false); // we don't care if the device is charging or not
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    }

    public void cancelAllJobs(View v) {
        JobScheduler tm = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        tm.cancelAll();
    }
    }
```

**TestJobService**:

```
public class TestJobService extends JobService {

    private final static String TAG = TestJobService.class.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.bullet("onStartJob"));

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
        Log.w(TAG, SubTag.bullet("onStopJob"));

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: found the solution ? i have the problem too

Answer (score 0):

I had to to add the follwoing line in the service tag in the manifest:

```
android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
```